# Do Unix Interface Naming Rules Exist?

Tags: unix-philosophy, historical-unix

I realized, that on Unix - systems a lot of weird interface acronyms exist:

- lo = loopback interface
- eno = ethernet interface, network interface card
- ens = ethernet interface, on newer Ubuntu version

What is the rule behind this namings and is there any? 
What do the short-hand "nick-names" mean?

Comment: @muru thanks, I think it is part of the question, because without the naming rule, I wouldnt be able to understand the definition of ens, eno and lo at all, and every naming issue in future, therefore I specifically asked for the ruling on this topic.

Comment: You did read all the answers?

Comment: There is no standard for naming network interfaces on "Unix systems". Linux seems to do things differently from the BSD unices, for example. Could you narrow the question down to a particular Unix, or if Linux, to a particular family of Linux distributions?

Comment: @Kusalananda, possible group could be: Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: @muru, yes, I read the answers and I understood that the 'o' stands for 'on-board', fast reply by you, thx

Comment: this could be relevant: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/